# MVC Routing System

Tags: c#

What means the operator `:` when calling methods for example ? I see that it maps the name of the parameter's name inside the method. What means `name : "Default"` how to interpret it ? What is the name of this kind of calling method ?

```
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: perhaps question be changed to say what is a : operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called "named arguments", and I would not call it an operator. (There is a ?: operator though)

[Named and Optional Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)